# How can I look for certain words in a file and then do something?

Tags: vb.net

How can I look for certain words in a file then do something if any of the words were found?

I would like to do something if for example any of these words `banana` `horse` `window` `whatever` is found within a file.

Here is my last attempt

```
        Dim thefile As String = "C:\application\thefile"

    If File.Exists(thefile) Then
        Using reader As New StreamReader(thefile)
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()

                If line.Contains("Banana") OrElse line.Contains("horse") OrElse line.Contains("window") OrElse line.Contains("whatever") Then
                    msgbox("Word(s) found " & line)
                    Do_this_and_that()    
                Else
                    MsgBox("Word(s) not found")    


                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
        End Using
    Else
        msgbox("File not found")
    End If
```

There seem to be so many variations of doing this, but I can't get them to work when its multiple words instead of just one. What is the easies and cleanest way of doing this?

Comment: don't you want a Not in front of each of those conditions? you only have it on the first one.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I don't understand what you mean with "certain words in a file *and then* use an if statement" - do you want to find words and then do something else? Or do you (only) want to see if a word is among a certain collection of words?

Comment: Most certainly. Updated my question. If the words (just one word is enough) are found within the file, I want to do something else indeed. If they are not found, do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit of a performance issue, but you can try using a `List(Of String)` :

```
Dim thefile As String = "C:\application\thefile"
Dim toCheck as New List(of String)
'You can fill up your list by whoever you want
toCheck.Add("banana")
toCheck.Add("horse")
'...
Dim FoundWords As New List(Of String)

If File.Exists(thefile) Then
    Using reader As New StreamReader(thefile)
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()

            'We check our list to see if it matches
            For Each item in toCheck
                if line.Contains(item) then
                    FoundWords.Add(item)
                End If
            Next
        End While
    End Using

    If FoundWords.Count > 0 Then
        msgbox(FoundWords.Count.ToString() & " Word(s) found")
        Do_this_and_that()    
    Else
        MsgBox("Word(s) not found")    
    End If
Else
    msgbox("File not found")
End If
```

Now this can be improved but if you don't have thousand of words to look for that should do the trick...

Comment: Well its a very small file that I'm working with, so perhaps performance wont be an issue in my case. Any who, does this work if only one word of the words is the file? Both msgboxes showed up (words not found and words found)

Comment: Update... So now it will put all found words in a List, then tell how many words it found

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. :)

Comment: What if the line is "aaaa bananabanana ccc"? you code with return that the word "banana" has been found!! also what if the line is "a big BANANA" (notice the case), your code will return that "banana" has not been found.

Comment: Also the question says "do something if any of the words were found", not check if the word has been found or not

Comment: @user813948 Well "do something if the words were found" implies to find it... and about your first comment I agree, but that's fine tuning, if you want the complete word, add a space before and after each word. and about case sensitivity, it's possible to indicate the function to take care of it or not

Comment: @SuperPeanut adding the space wont work for "a banana. So whatever; ".. it's not fine tuning, it's just wrong. There is a lot of studies about how to tokenize especially words. My example is the way to do it with the bag of words to recognize and the tokenizer. Yours it's just a bad attempt to solve a well known problem

Comment: @user813948 Ok I think you have the right to calm down... I can understand your solution is the only and right way to do it. But you have to explain it better then. OP doesn't know what is tokenizing, neither regex...

Comment: @SuperPeanut I dont understand why I should calm down: I am very calm and try to explain you the flaws of your solution. There are many things to improve and change in mine and very open to criticism unlike you as I can see.. regarding MadsTheMan not knowing the meaning of  tokenize or regex or hashset is not my problem, there is plenty of documentation about and they teach those concepts in every course of computing!! You cant say a solution it's not a solution because someone dont understand it!!

Comment: @user813948 Ok I'm sorry about that. You're actually right. My solution is only partially working, which means it's not a good one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tokenize the line and use a HashSet. That is the fastest method. Put all the words in the HashSet and then check if each word is init:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        var file = @"C:\application\thefile";
        var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "banana", "horse", "window", "whatever" }.Select(x => x.ToLower()));

        foreach (var word in GetWords(file))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);

            if (hashSet.Contains(word))
            {
                //DoSomething();
                Console.WriteLine("\tFound!!");
                //Continue or Break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetWords(string file)
    {
        var rg = new Regex(@"[^\p{L}]");
        const int bufferLen = 512;

        using (var reader = File.OpenText(file))
        {
            var word = new StringBuilder();

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var buffer = new char[bufferLen];

                var readChars = reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, bufferLen);

                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; i++)
                {
                    if (rg.IsMatch(buffer[i].ToString()))//end of the word
                    {
                        if (word.Length > 0)
                        {
                            yield return word.ToString();
                            word = new StringBuilder();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        word.Append(Char.ToLowerInvariant(buffer[i]));
                }
            }

            if (word.Length > 0)
                yield return word.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and here in VB

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim filename = "C:\application\thefile"
        Dim words() As String = {"banana", "horse", "window", "whatever"}
        Dim bagOfWords = New HashSet(Of String)(words.Select(Function(x) x.ToLower()))

        For Each word As String In GetWords(filename)
            Console.WriteLine(word)

            If bagOfWords.Contains(word) Then
                'DoSomething();                
                Console.WriteLine(vbTab & "Found!!")

                'Exit For if you need to terminate here;
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Iterator Function GetWords(filename As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Dim rg = New Regex("[^\p{L}]")
        Const bufferLen As Integer = 512

        Using reader As New StreamReader(filename)
            Dim word = New StringBuilder()

            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                Dim buffer = New Char(bufferLen - 1) {}

                Dim readChars = reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, bufferLen)

                For i As Integer = 0 To readChars - 1
                    If rg.IsMatch(buffer(i).ToString()) Then
                        'end of the word
                        If word.Length > 0 Then
                            Yield word.ToString()
                            word = New StringBuilder()
                        End If
                    Else
                        word.Append([Char].ToLowerInvariant(buffer(i)))
                    End If
                Next
            End While

            If word.Length > 0 Then
                Yield word.ToString()
            End If
        End Using
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: If you need something more sophisticated for splitting words, you should look into something similar to nltk but for .net

Comment: Both `Tokenize` and `HashSet` are two unfamiliar words to me, I'll do some research on that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you translate from C#? I put a small code snippet but unfortunately it's in c#'. For getting words, I have used a regular expression. For hashset, it very simple concept, you should look out here https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.Generic.HashSet%601.%23ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Comment: I cannot, but I'll have a look and give it a try.